# Android wifiManager getScanResults always return null

Tags: android

According to a lot of official documents also stackoverflow documents, I am trying to use wifimanager to get list of access points near me but that is not working. I want to tell you I tried to use below code in android 4.4 but right now not working in android 9. Have you any solution?

```
     final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        //****************** Enable Wifi And Connect To Hidden Access Point

        if(wifiManager.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

            wifistate = true;
        }
        // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            int count = 0;

            public void run() {
                while (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false && count < 5) {
                    try {
                        // Here I'm making thread sleep to show progress
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        count++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }


                if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == true) {

                    //
                    wifiManager.startScan();
                    List<ScanResult> wifiScanList =wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

Comment: Hi! Did you try this code on emulator or real device?

Comment: Dear guys, I found the problem and solved that. In android 5 and above we should turn on location (GPS) and then try to connect specific point. I hope this comment will be useful to other developers.

Comment: Hi @mehdi your solution also did the trick for me. 
You should answer your own question so others can find the solution more easily.